# why the function Fn::GetAtt function give me error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I try to use fn::GetAtt function to calculate the permission and ref. my cloudformation json is:
The defined resource part is:

```
"Resources": {
"helloworld": {
  "Properties": {
    "AutoPublishAlias": "live",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "Runtime": "nodejs6.10",
    "CodeUri": "s3://ss-sheng/src/helloWorld.zip",
    "Role": {
      "Ref": "dependrole"
    },
    "Timeout": 3,
    "ReservedConcurrentExecutions": 5,
    "Tags": {
      "PROJECT": "My Point",
      "COST_CENTRE": "6400073401",
      "BUSINESS_UNIT": "My Programs",
      "BUSINESS_CONTACT": "Greg Windsor",
      "TIER": "Development"
    }
  },
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function"
},
"helloworldpermission": {
  "DependsOn": "helloworld",
  "Properties": {
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "FunctionName": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        ":",
        [
          {
            "Ref": "helloworld"
          },
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "helloworld",
              "Version"
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
}
}
```

I get the error:

```
Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute
```

I give them two parameters already "helloworld" and "Version".
Why lambda function still show me error?

The helloworld ref the serverless function helloworld.

I use "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31", which is defined at the beginning of the cloud-formation file.

Comment: What you are referring through this   "Resources": {
"helloworld": {
    "Role": {
      "Ref": "dependrole".  I don't see it's definition in template

Comment: According to this:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html, the only attribute you are able to get from a "AWS::Serverless::Function" resource is "Arn".  "AWS::Lambda::Version" is a standalone resource.

Comment: @PrabhatSingh You want to see which definition? the dependrole? that is parameter defined in front of this paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource, you can access the `version` and `alias` using `Ref`

For more information, refer to the following link :

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#referencing-lambda-version--alias-resources

Thus, rather than

```
{
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "helloworld",
          "Version"
        ]
      }
```

it should be,

```
{
        "Fn::Ref": [
          "helloworld",
          "Version"
        ]
      }
```